# Unable to enclose double quotes inside string in R

Tags: r

unable to enclose "hey" in double quotes within a string . I am unable to get output as Hey "Hey"

```
ad<- "hey"
fd<- paste("Hey","",ad,sep="")
```

Comment: Input: "hey"? Output: hey? Then `cat(ad)` does the job. Is it required to addittionally replace h by H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`dQuote`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sQuote.html) function is made for this:

```r
dQuote("hey")
# [1] "\"hey\""
```

Note that depending on the OS and your environment, it might add "fancy quotes" (angled/directional double-quotes). They may look good but if you want to reuse the results as a string in R, it won't work because R does not recognize its smart quotes as string-boundaries. You can explicitly disable it with `dQuote(., q=FALSE)`. (The default is `FALSE` on windows except for the Rgui console, but I believe the default is `TRUE` elsewhere.)

Depending on your need, you may also like `shQuote` due to its escaping of existing embedded quotes:

```r
cat(dQuote('"hey" there'), "\n")
# ""hey" there"                        # may not be right

cat(shQuote('"hey" there'), "\n")
# "\"hey\" there"
```

though whether that is correct depends on your needs; `shQuote` was designed for shell-quoting/escaping.

Ultimately in your example, I think you would use

```r
ad <- "Hey"
paste("Hey", dQuote(ad))
# [1] "Hey \"Hey\""
```

Comment: That's very interresting. I never heard of those functions before. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes can be added with

```
paste0('"', "Hey", '"')
#[1] "\"Hey\""
```

Or

```
sprintf('"%s"', "Hey")
#[1] "\"Hey\""
```

Note that R displays strings with double quotes (`"`) so to show double quotes as part of string it escapes it with backslash `\`. To see actual string you may use `cat` on it.

```
cat(paste0('"', "Hey", '"'))
#"Hey"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write raw strings like:

```r
r"{"Hey"}"
r'{"Hey"}'
[1] "\"hey\""
```

See `?Quotes`

> Raw character constants are also available using a syntax similar to the one used in C++: r"(...)" with ... any character sequence, except that it must not contain the closing sequence )". The delimiter pairs [] and {} can also be used, and R can be used in place of r. For additional flexibility, a number of dashes can be placed between the opening quote and the opening delimiter, as long as the same number of dashes appear between the closing delimiter and the closing quote.